# Sending Down key with WebDriverJS

Tags: accessibility, webdriver-io

I am writing an acceptance test using Webdriver.io, Mocha & Chai which involves navigating around some autocomplete lists using only the keyboard.

I have used the API's inbuilt keys() function as below to send a Tab key press, a string 'Hello' and then an Enter key press.

```
it('should be navigable using only the keyboard', () =>
  browser
    .keys('Tab')
    .keys('Hello')
    .keys('Enter')
    //more steps
);
```

The problem occurs when I need to send a press of the down arrow key to select an option from the autocomplete list. I've tried the following:

```
browser
  .keys('Down')
  .keys('Down_arrow')
```

and other similar variations, but these just result in the string 'Down' being sent to the autocomplete box rather than a down key press being simulated.

I have checked the [webdriver.io API documentation for the keys() function](http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/keys.html) but it just points you in the direction of the Selenium gihub repo and I haven't been able to find any information on keys from that.

Answer (score 0):

I've now solved this. The answer was

```
.keys('Down arrow')
```

So close!

It turns out the documentation is now in the wiki section of the repo and the keys info is under [JsonWireProtocol](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#user-content-sessionsessionidelementidvalue).